# spring boot 1.5.7 cannot inject bean defination by annotation @Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, redis, jedis

I need a redisClient that I configure a Jedis pool.code as this:

```
@Configuration
public class RedisConfiguration {  

@Bean(name= "jedis.pool")  
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public JedisPool jedisPool(@Qualifier("jedis.pool.config") JedisPoolConfig config,   
            @Value("${jedis.pool.host}")String host,   
            @Value("${jedis.pool.port}")int port,@Value("${jedis.pool.timeout}")int timeout,@Value("${jedis.pool.password}")String password) {  
    return new JedisPool(config, host, port, timeout, password);  
}  

@Bean(name= "jedis.pool.config")  
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig (@Value("${jedis.pool.config.maxTotal}")int maxTotal,  
                            @Value("${jedis.pool.config.maxIdle}")int maxIdle,  
                            @Value("${jedis.pool.config.maxWaitMillis}")int maxWaitMillis) {  
    JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();  
    config.setMaxTotal(maxTotal);  
    config.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);  
    config.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWaitMillis);  
    return config;  
}      
}
```

`RedisClient` class like this:

```
@Service
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class RedisClient {  

@Resource(name="jedis.pool")
private JedisPool jedisPool;

public void set(String key, String value){  
    Jedis jedis = null;  
    try {
        jedis = jedisPool.getResource();  
        jedis.set(key, value);  
    } finally {
        if(jedis!=null) 
            jedis.close();  
    }
}
```

I use `RedisClient` like this:

```
@Autowired
private RedisClient redisClient;
```

but when the code runs the place use redisClient it throws `NullPointerException`.

Comment: the second part of code is RedisClient.java

Comment: What the packages for `RedisConfiguration` and `RedisClient` ? Please show you `SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: sorry,I saw this reply just now.My application java file like this:\@SpringBootApplication
\@EnableAutoConfiguration
\@EnableConfigurationProperties
\@MapperScan("com.heysound.content.app.mapper")
public class ContentApplication {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(ContentApplication.class, args);
 }
}

Comment: Could you please add the actual stacktrace and the code where it fails

Comment: the finally answer is that:because I use a instance what created manual and include a reference of spring bean . so that I cannot create that instance successfully ,then I change the reference from spring bean to a normal class reference.Hope you can understand.I'm not sure I express correctly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.. however, to provide any help, I'd need to see the stacktrace and the code where the NullPointer is thrown.

Comment: I mean that if I want to create a bean manual ,then the beans that depends on it must be created manual,if I use a bean created by dependency injection ,then the manual create bean cannot be used.